# How can I mark right angles in tkz-euclide with round quarter-circle and a dot?

Tags: tkz-euclide

I am currently re-creating this Wikipedia image:

[image]

Source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Thaleskreis.png

The image I currently have is good, but I miss the round right-angle markers with dots:

[image]

Source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Triangle-thales-circle.svg

Is there a possibility to re-define the `\tkzMarkRightAngle` to use the other notation (which is commonly used in school in Germany).

### MWE

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzSetUpPoint[shape=circle,size=10,color=black,fill=black]
    \tkzSetUpLine[line width=1]
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O, -5/0/A, 5/0/B, 5/5/M, -5/5/N}
    \tkzDefPoint(60:5){X}
    \tkzDefPoint(150:5){Y}

    \tkzDrawArc[color=black, thick, fill=gray!20](O,B)(A)

    % Avoid too long edges of polygon
    \tkzClipPolygon(A,B,M,N)
    \tkzClipCircle(O,B)

    % Draw polygons and mark right angle
    \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=red,fill opacity=0.5](A,B,X)
    \tkzMarkRightAngle(A,X,B)

    \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=blue,fill opacity=0.5](A,B,Y)
    \tkzMarkRightAngle(A,Y,B)

    % lines should not colored
    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,X)
    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,Y)

    \tkzDrawArc[color=black, thick](O,B)(A)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think right angle must be a right angle without the arc. In the first one it only says that the angles are equal.

Comment: @percusse In schools in Germany an angle with a dot denote always a right angle. Probably not the best notation, but very common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `pic[draw,...]{angle=p1--p2--p3}` construct instead of `\tkzMarkRightAngle(p1,p2,p3)` then. This can be done easily as the following:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}

\begin{document}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1]\Large
    \tkzSetUpPoint[shape=circle,size=10,color=black,fill=black]
    \tkzSetUpLine[line width=1]
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O, -5/0/A, 5/0/B, 5/5/M, -5/5/N}
    \tkzDefPoint(60:5){X}
    \tkzDefPoint(150:5){Y}

    \tkzDrawArc[color=black, thick, fill=gray!20](O,B)(A)

    % Avoid too long edges of polygon
    \tkzClipPolygon(A,B,M,N)
    \tkzClipCircle(O,B)

    % Draw polygons and mark right angle
    \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=red,fill opacity=0.5](A,B,X)
    \draw pic[draw, angle radius=3mm,"$\cdot$",angle eccentricity=.6]{angle= A--X--B};

    \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=blue,fill opacity=0.5](A,B,Y)
    \draw pic[draw, angle radius=3mm,"$\cdot$",angle eccentricity=.6]{angle= A--Y--B};

    % lines should not colored
    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,X)
    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,Y)

    \tkzDrawArc[color=black, thick](O,B)(A)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with the required output:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here is the `tkz-euclide` way of doing it.

```
\tkzMarkAngle[thick,size=0.4](A,X,B)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.25](A,X,B){$\cdot$}
```

and

```
\tkzMarkAngle[thick,size=0.4](A,Y,B)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.25](A,Y,B){$\cdot$}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzSetUpPoint[shape=circle,size=10,color=black,fill=black]
    \tkzSetUpLine[line width=1]
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O, -5/0/A, 5/0/B, 5/5/M, -5/5/N}
    \tkzDefPoint(60:5){X}
    \tkzDefPoint(150:5){Y}

    \tkzDrawArc[color=black, thick, fill=gray!20](O,B)(A)

    % Avoid too long edges of polygon
    \tkzClipPolygon(A,B,M,N)
    \tkzClipCircle(O,B)

    % Draw polygons and mark right angle
    \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=red,fill opacity=0.5](A,B,X)
    \tkzMarkAngle[thick,size=0.4](A,X,B)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.25](A,X,B){$\cdot$}

    \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=blue,fill opacity=0.5](A,B,Y)
    \tkzMarkAngle[thick,size=0.4](A,Y,B)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.25](A,Y,B){$\cdot$}

    % lines should not colored
    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,X)
    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,Y)

    \tkzDrawArc[color=black, thick](O,B)(A)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With the new version of tkz-euclide [here](http://altermundus.fr/files/euclide/geom_2.45b.zip)
The macro  `\tkzMarkRightAngle` has a new option : german

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O, -5/0/A, 5/0/B, 5/5/M, -5/5/N}
    \tkzDefPoint(60:5){X}
    \tkzDefPoint(150:5){Y}
    \tkzDrawArc[color=black, thick, fill=gray!20](O,B)(A)
    \tkzClipPolygon(A,B,M,N)
    \tkzClipCircle(O,B)
    \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=red,fill opacity=0.5](A,B,X)
    \tkzMarkRightAngle[german,size=.5,line width=0.8pt](A,X,B)
    \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=blue,fill opacity=0.5](A,B,Y)
    \tkzMarkRightAngle[german,size=.5,line width=0.8pt](A,Y,B)
    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,X)
    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,Y)
    \tkzDrawArc[color=black, thick](O,B)(A)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]